# How to check for overflow converting char*[] to unsigned short

Tags: c++

I am trying to convert a user input into unsigned short:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    unsigned short tl;
    tl = (unsigned short) strtoul(argv[2], NULL, 0);
}
```

For example: a user input of "555555" overflows and becomes 31267.

How can I stop/check for overflows while also trying to convert the input? What is the most efficient and effective way to stop that from happening?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at the documentation of [strtoul on cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtoul)

> If the converted value falls out of range of corresponding return type, range error occurs and ULONG_MAX or ULLONG_MAX is returned.

You should be able to detect this by checking `errno` for `ERANGE`.

Something like this should therefore work for you:

```
#include <limits>
#include <cerror>

auto n = strtoul(argv[2], NULL, 0);
if (errno == ERANGE || n > std::numeric_limits<unsigned short>::max()) {
  // Handle overflow
}
else {
  // Do something
}
```